# Wait for the system() call to complete

Tags: c, multithreading, system, wait

In the code below I am calling `system` with `"gedit filename"`. It's opening `gedit`  with the specified file correctly.
However, in the next line I am trying to print the modified data (which I am going to update through `gedit`), but it will not wait until `gedit` exits.

```
strcpy(tt1,"gedit ");
strcat(tt1,tt);
system(tt1);                     //here gedit opens file

printf("\nFile data %s  Location %s",getFileData(tt),tt); //this line executes before finishing gedit
```

Please help me to wait till the `system()` call completes its work.

Comment: What does `tt` contain?

Comment: `gedit` probably forks into the background like a daemon, many gui programs do.

Comment: tt contains file name which will be used for gedit e.g. gedit abc.txt   here tt is abc.txt

Comment: When you call `gedit filename` from the shell, does the shell prompt return before you exit gedit?

Comment: There is no way to do this..???

Comment: Yes Daniel... When I invoke gedit filename from the shell ,the propt just returns.. :(

Comment: Can anybody suggest another editor which don't do this kind of things...

Comment: `system(3)` waits until the called command finishes before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is handled by the `--wait` command line argument, which does seem to be a pretty [recent addition](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/commit/gedit/gedit-app.c?id=ee95e4ce2844dd1277afb28780f49da560e2452f). You could try building gedit on your own, to at least verify if it works (since your distro probably won't have a recent-enough build).

Comment: hey hey ...Thanks unwind ....It worked and solved the problem...Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks Thanks  unwind..